# Need to disable dragging in jScrollPane

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, drag

I'm using [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) for my HTML page. I want to disable the scrollDrag functionality because I need only Up and down arrow to scroll the page not by dragging the track/dragger
How to do?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to remove the scroll bar in the jScrollPane?

Comment: No, I need only up and down arrow to be work. Not the dragger(which is in center portion.

Comment: or If I press up/down arrow, it should scroll the content not by dragging the bar.

Answer (score 0):

`JScrollPane` inherits the `processMouseMotionEvent()` from `JComponent` If you were to override the inherited `processMouseMotionEvent()` with you own version you could then choose to ignore the `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED` event

Comment: Question is about JavaScript jScrollPane, not Java

Answer (score 0):

```
.jspDrag {
    background:#bbd;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    **display:none;**
}
```